# Running Magento 2's Provided Code Sniffs

Tags: magento2, github, phpcs

Magento 2 seems to include a set of [PHP code sniffs](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/.php_cs.dist) in the source repository.  How can I, as a third party developer, use the `phpcs` tool to run these sniffs against my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [PhpCsFixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) configuration file, not the code sniffer rules itself

> Instead of using command line options to customize the rule, you can save the project configuration in a .php_cs.dist file in the root directory of your project. The file must return an instance of PhpCsFixer\ConfigInterface which lets you configure the rules, the files and directories that need to be analyzed.

Example of command:

```
php-cs-fixer fix --config=.php_cs.dist -v --dry-run --stop-on-violation --using-cache=no
```

This fixer can be added to the pre-commit hook as well.

Ruleset for the code sniffer is in the [ruleset.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/ruleset.xml)

Comment: For anyone else that comes along -- php-cs-fixer is separate tool from phpcs and phpcbf

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pre-commit hook to check the staged files, there is one in:

```
dev/tools/Magento/Tools/StaticReview/pre-commit
```

Instead, if you want to test a specific file you can run the `phpcs` executable inside `vendor/bin` like this:

```
path/to/magento/vendor/bin/phpcs filetotest.php
```

and you can fix eventual errors with:

```
path/to/magento/vendor/bin/phpcbf filetotest.php
```

Comment: Thank you fro responding -- but it's also unclear how you'd use run this pre-commit script against a PHP file?

Comment: @AlanStorm i've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're asking to simply run the command all on your own. Try this. Remove `--dry-run` to have it automatically apply the fixes.

```
php /path/to/php-cs-fixer --dry-run --diff --verbose fix /path/to/your/code --config /path/to/magento/.php_cs
```